# How to change ListView Item programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, listview, listitem

I have a ListView and I want to change the listitem of it programmatically. Is there any way to do this? Thank you in advance.

This is my ListView XML code.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/foodsListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:stackFromBottom="false"
    android:transcriptMode="disabled"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_food">
</ListView>
```

And here is what I want to show instead of `item_food`:

```
"R.layout.item_message"
```

Comment: `tools` is just for the preview window - it has no bearing on what you see at runtime. Look up a tutorial for ListView.

Comment: Well thanks... So is that a NO for my question?

Comment: You don't change `listitem` programmatically - you just update your ListView. The `listitem` attribute has no relationship to what you see in your app when it runs. It only exists so developers can have a preview of how their app will look when it launches.

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView instead of ListView. It was create for this t